# How to rename selected objects using python?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I want to rename a large number of items. Doing so manually could take quite some time. I want to use python to rename the object. To find out the python command for renaming I renamed an object manually and looked in the console for the echoed command. The command was:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
```

This command does not seem to be the correct command for renaming. It does not even contain the new name in the command. I also tried to look up the python command reference for the name, but the link was a dead end.

**How can I rename an object using python?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can access them by iterating and assign the name property:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.name = "newName"
```

Blender automatically add `.001`, `.002` and so on to `newName` if another datablock of same type and name already exists. You may need to check a name pattern within the `for`-loop.

Another example - rename all Mesh objects in current scene that start with `C` (e.g. `Cube`, case insensitive):

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH' and obj.name.lower().startswith("c")
        obj.name = "newName"
```

Comment: could you add the command for the selected objects?

Answer (score 1):

In case your object has `obj.data`, make sure you change the name under `.data` too:

```
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.name = "newName"
    obj.data.name = "newName"
```

Objects such as [empties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/empties.html) do not have data.